# Iterating through a vector while other threads may modify it

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

I am not experienced in multithreading, however I need it in socket programming. My problem is, that I need to iterate through a static vector of my class, however, while I do that, other threads delete elements from that vector, which crashes my program. I assume I need to somehow lock the vector, I can't figure out how. The only solution I found seems to be Windows specific (Concurrency::concurrent_vector). This is my code:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

std::vector<User*> User::users;
std::mutex mtx;

int main() {
  //...
  mtx.lock();
  for (int i = 0; i < User::users.size(); ++i) {
    User::users.at(i)->stop = true;
    User::users.at(i)->shutdownSocket();
  }
  mtx.unlock();
}
```

This seemingly does not lock the vector. I am using CLion on Ubuntu. How can I safely do this?

Edit: I have included mtx.lock() and unlock() everywhere, where I am accessing the vector. I have double checked that.

Does it matter that I use one mutex declared in my main.cpp and one in User.h? Do I have to use the same mutex for the same vector?

Comment: This most certainly locks the vector. But unless all other execution threads also lock the vector, too, this won't work. Please see your C++ book for more information.

Comment: Hi. Out of curiosity, how would you handle a case where you are currently reading what should is about to get deleted ? is it a big deal to keep reading until that element is entirely processed ? If that's the case, you could get away without having any `std::mutex` by simply having a `std::atomic<bool>`in each of your User instance. Let your other threads mark it for deletion, and let the reading thread erase or skip the actual instances. We can certainly advise based on what your requirements are. Multithreading in a nutshell: `std::mutex` is costly, `std::atomic<>` variables are cheaper.

Comment: @Peter I cast neither of those things, but the reason is likely that at least a token quantity of prior research is required here and this is a fairly basic question that could be answered with any introductory tutorial or book on multi-threaded programming in C++. We are not here to replace such learning materials. It would not have taken long to learn the requisite subject matter had prior effort been applied. "Stack Overflow first, work later" is an increasing problem.

Comment: You say the only solution you found was `Concurrency::concurrent_vector` and Windows-specific, then the only code you show is something completely different, which is not. What problem did you encounter with `std::mutex`? What resources did you employ to learn how to use it?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I am sorry for the inconvenience, I will be studying multithreading in depth later in a different course, right now I only needed to solve this problem as fast as possible. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does it matter that I use one mutex declared in my main.cpp and one in User.h? Do I have to use the same mutex for the same vector?

Yes, and yes.

You use one mutex to synchronise the resource across multiple threads.

Different mutexes do not know about each other.

A mutex is like a set of traffic lights. When one post turns red, the other turns green. That's because they're controlled by the same cabinet on the corner of the road, that knows how to make the change happen at the right time, in the right order, for both posts in concert. The traffic lights down the street are controlled by a completely different cabinet, and control a different junction, and can't help you manage traffic at the first junction; if you pretend that it does, you'll eventually get a big crash.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! This was the information I needed.